# Magento 2.1.2 - PHP Parse Error in Bootstrap.php when trying to execute bin/magento commands

Tags: php, ssh, bin-magento

Can't seem to find a fix for this issue. I'm running Magento 2.1.2 with PHP 7.0.16, however there are different versions of PHP installed on different websites on the same VPS.

When trying to execute magento/bin commands, it seems to throw the same error with any - however the most recent I've tried is:

```
 php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

It throws the following errors:

```
PHP Warning: Cannot open '/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_browscap.ini' for reading in Unknown on line 0
PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in ***/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php on line 411
```

The function which includes line 411 is as follows, with the problem line surrounded by **:

```
public function isDeveloperMode()
{
    $mode = 'default';
    if (isset($this->server[State::PARAM_MODE])) {
        $mode = $this->server[State::PARAM_MODE];
    } else {
     ** $deploymentConfig = $this->getObjectManager()->get(DeploymentConfig::class); **
        $configMode = $deploymentConfig->get(State::PARAM_MODE);
        if ($configMode) {
            $mode = $configMode;
        }
    }

    return $mode == State::MODE_DEVELOPER;
}
```

The only details I can find online relate to there being an incompatible installation of PHP, but that shouldn't be an issue as I'm running 7.0.16?

Comment: what's in `Bootstrap.php` on line 411? In the latest version on github there is this https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Bootstrap.php#L411 which does not make much sense.

Comment: @Marius I'll edit the question so I can include the entire function

Answer (score 2):

Turned out to be an issue with multiple versions of PHP being installed on the same VPS and running Plesk. Setting up an independent VPS only running PHP 7.0.16 fixed the errors.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone else comes across this, it was solved by changing the default version of php to the latest one in plesk

```
For example, my system php is 5.5:
$ php -v
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.11 (cli) (built: Jul 2 2015 15:23:08)
$ which php
/usr/bin/php

But I want to use php 5.6 installed by Plesk:
$ /opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/php -v
PHP 5.6.13 (cli) (built: Sep 8 2015 11:53:39)
$ export PATH=/opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin:$PATH
$ php -v
PHP 5.6.13 (cli) (built: Sep 8 2015 11:53:39)

$ which php
/opt/plesk/php/5.6/bin/php
```